# Error 1822 MySql Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql

I know this has been asked two million times, but I have hit a point of just staring at this thing for hours not knowing what gives.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Branch`;
CREATE TABLE `Branch` (
`BranchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`SKU` INT NOT NULL,
`BranchName` tinytext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (BranchID, SKU)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Items`;
CREATE TABLE `Items` (
`SKU` INT NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`Price` float,
`Quantity` INT,
`BranchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SKU),
FOREIGN KEY (SKU) REFERENCES Branch(SKU),
foreign key (BranchID) REFERENCES Branch(BranchID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For whatever reason I am getting the 1822 error and I just cannot see where it's coming from (probably something stupid).  I have put them in the order they are being created in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Drop your `items` first before your `branch`. Because it has foreign key to table `Branch`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Items`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Branch`;
CREATE TABLE `Branch` (
`BranchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`SKU` INT NOT NULL,
`BranchName` tinytext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (BranchID, SKU)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Items` (
`SKU` INT NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`Price` float,
`Quantity` INT,
`BranchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SKU),
FOREIGN KEY (SKU) REFERENCES Branch(SKU),
foreign key (BranchID) REFERENCES Branch(BranchID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: That ends in the 1824 error as the branch table is no longer existent for items to reference.

Comment: @KieCam, yes drop your items first then create your branch.

Comment: That is what I have done, and I get Error Code: 1824.  Failed to open the referenced table 'branch'

Comment: If i run the commands manually in order I end with an 1822, if I run the whole script it ends with the inability to reference the table

Answer (score 0):

'InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html branch.sku does not meet this requirement.